# ASP.NET IEnumerable view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable` view that returns a list of Remarks, but I also have a menu that has a link with a student number from a different entity that is linked to Remarks, it's hard to explain, so I'll post my code

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/StudentGegevens/index/"+ Model.LRL_NR)" class="buttonStudentGegevens"><img src="../../images/ViewAccount.png"/> Student gegevens </a>
<a href="@Url.Content("~/StudentGegevens/MedischeInformatie/" +@Model.LRL_NR)" class="buttonMedischeInformatie"><img src="../../images/ViewMedischeInfo.png"/> Medische informatie </a>
<a href="@Url.Content("~/StudentGegevens/BijlageenCommentaar/" +@Model.LRL_NR)" class="buttonBijlagenCommentaar"><img src="../../images/ViewBijlage.png"/> Bijlage en commentaar </a>
```

a `foreach(var item in Model)` wouldn't work because I only want the menu displayed once.

As you can see here, I give the student number to the link with `@Model.LRL_NR`, but with an `IEnumerable` view, you cannot do `@Model.LRL_NR`, is there any way I can use `@Model.LRL_NR` with an `IEnumerable` view?

Comment: What kind of `IEnumerable`? Are you not using a generic one? If you are using a collection, you should be iterating over it, no?

Comment: @model IEnumerable<PvBempty.STUDENT>, and if I am able to iterate over it, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over your `IEnumerable` and for each item in it write out the links:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
     <a href="@Url.Content("~/StudentGegevens/index/"+ item.LRL_NR)" class="buttonStudentGegevens"><img src="../../images/ViewAccount.png"/> Student gegevens </a>
     <a href="@Url.Content("~/StudentGegevens/MedischeInformatie/" +@item.LRL_NR)" class="buttonMedischeInformatie"><img src="../../images/ViewMedischeInfo.png"/> Medische informatie </a>
     <a href="@Url.Content("~/StudentGegevens/BijlageenCommentaar/" +@item.LRL_NR)" class="buttonBijlagenCommentaar"><img src="../../images/ViewBijlage.png"/> Bijlage en commentaar </a>
}
```

---

From your description, you need to access both `LRL_NR` and the list of `REMARK`.

One way to do this is to have a class that encapsulates them and that you use as your `Model`:

```
public class RemarksModel
{
   public int LRL_NR { get; set }
   public IEnumerable<PvBempty.REMARK> Remarks { get; set }
}
```

This would allow you to do:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/StudentGegevens/index/"+ Model.LRL_NR)" class="buttonStudentGegevens"><img src="../../images/ViewAccount.png"/> Student gegevens </a>
<a href="@Url.Content("~/StudentGegevens/MedischeInformatie/" +@Model.LRL_NR)" class="buttonMedischeInformatie"><img src="../../images/ViewMedischeInfo.png"/> Medische informatie </a>
<a href="@Url.Content("~/StudentGegevens/BijlageenCommentaar/" +@Model.LRL_NR)" class="buttonBijlagenCommentaar"><img src="../../images/ViewBijlage.png"/> Bijlage en commentaar </a>

foreach(var item in Model.Remarks)
{
    // each item is a PvBempty.REMARK
}
```

Comment: Yes but if I were to do this, I'd show the menu for EVERY item in the model, I just want to show the menu once.

Below the menu, I have a list of students (with a datatable)

Comment: @user1841216 - Then you shouldn't use `IEnumerable<PvBempty.STUDENT>` for your model, but `PvBempty.STUDENT`. Why use a collection if you only have one item to display?

Comment: Because below the menu I have a list of students in a datatable, could this problem be fixed with a partial view?

Comment: @user1841216 - OK. But where does `LRL_NR` come from? Is it the same for each item in the list of `PvBempty.STUDENT`? Consider creating a class that contains this item _and_ a list of `PvBempty.STUDENT`. This will let you access the property directly.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer to me. Maybe the simple fix would be to just grab the first instance of Student in your Model? (var item in Model.SingleOrDefault()) (using the same @foreach logic that is)

Comment: No, I have 400 students in the datatable, all with a different student number. the LRL_NR is just for the link, so that you're working with the right student. I've explained this all wrong, it's actually a list of remarks, and the LRL_NR is so that you have the right number for the link

Comment: SingleOrDefault doesn't work for some reason. foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'PvBempty.REMARK' because 'PvBempty.REMARK' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Sounds like your model is **not** an `IEnumerable` or `PvBempty.STUDENT` , but a `PvBempty.REMARK`.